# How to replicate Rocket League boost mechanic in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In rocket league, you are able to boost based on the direction you are facing. If the nose of your car is pointed upwards and you boost, there will be a force applied upwards. If the nose of your car is pointed to the left and down, a force is applied left and down. I'm trying to replicate this in Unity 3d, but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm assuming the boost should be based off the rotation, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I've tried all sorts of things.

My current code is

```
        theRB.AddRelativeForce(transform.forward * boostAmount);
```

where theRB is the rigidbody for the car and boost amount is the magnitude of boost.
I've also tried using the transform and doing transform.translate, but the car doesn't apply boost in the right direction (up and down).

Using AddRelativeForce doesn't work, AddForce doesn't work, Transform.translate doesn't work, I'm slowly giving up hope.

The car boosts forward initially, gives a jerk, and goes back to the starting place. When I try to boost upwards, it does it, but I can't control it in the air (I've set up proper car control in the air) and I can't boost downwards. I can't change the direction of the boost.

Comment: The code you have should work.  Try changing the [ForceMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html) used.

Comment: You'll need to post more of your code. The line you posted looks fine, but the mechanic working like you want it to depends on how it is called.